# Is there a way to declare a ClassVar in a dataclass without importing typing?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I have a small and simple class like so:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Info:
    title: str
    description: str
```

Now, I want to make it have a custom repr, but I want to be able to toggle it. I added a `simple_repr` class variable to do the toggling.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Info:
    title: str
    description: str
    simple_repr: ClassVar = False

    def __repr__(self):
        if type(self).simple_repr:
            return f"<{self.title} - {self.description}>"
        kwargs = (f"{name}={value!r}" for name, value in asdict(self).items())
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({', '.join(kwargs)})"
```

This is all good, except that it doesn't work. Running the following outputs something unexpected.

```py
>>> info = Info("title", "description")
>>> 
>>> Info.simple_repr = True
>>> print(info)
<title - description>
>>> 
>>> Info.simple_repr = False
>>> print(info)
Info(title='title', description='description', simple_repr=False)
```

I know of a working solution, but it uses `typing` which is slow and unnecessary:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import ClassVar

@dataclass
class Info:
    title: str
    description: str
    simple_repr: ClassVar = False

    def __repr__(self):
        if type(self).simple_repr:
            return f"<{self.title} - {self.description}>"
        vars = asdict(self)
        kwargs = (f"{name}={value!r}" for name, value in vars.items())
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({', '.join(kwargs)})"
```

Is there a way to fix this so that `print(info)` shows `Info(title='title', description='description')`? I'd like to not import typing as it's unnecessary. (Python 3.10 will have `from __future__ import annotations`, meaning `import typing` will become redundant.)

Comment: "but it uses ``typing`` which is slow and unnecessary" Can you clarify this sentiment, so that answer do not violate the implied assumptions as well? ``typing`` has builtin speedups and is imported via some library anyway, making ``import typing`` either very fast or even instant. On top, it is not unnecessary as the error shows.

Comment: I've heard that typing was slow to use, which was why `from __future__ import annotations` was introduced in 3.7 as a way around importing it. It looks like dataclasses requires you to import it however, so I've basically found my answer: No.

Comment: Typing was slow, but since many libraries use it anyway even on old versions typing your own code is negligible. The future import serves primarily to allow forward references; performance improvements are just a bonus.

Comment: Ah so I should still import typing (even when there's string annotations) for clarity I guess. Thanks for explaining the main reason behind the `__future__` import. I learned something new :D